Is the Fermi level is same for the all solids?
If the solids at T=0k , the topmost energy level occupied by electrons in valence band is called Fermi level. Is this Fermi level is constant for all the materials? It is shown as same for metal, semiconductor and insulator in the pic. (given below). Moreover if this true, is conduction band energy levels vary for each type?


Those pictures are made by aligning the Fermi level. Different materials have different Fermi levels, and when they are touching each other, something interesting happens. That is how semiconductors work.

@naturallyInconsistent  thanks for reply , what about conduction band?

The whole picture moves when you align the Fermi level.

That's seems right, that Fermi level differ for materials. if we consider that above point, then conduction band energy levels located similar for all three cases, is this correct?

No, the location of conduction band (and valence band) differ for all materials too, even relative to the Fermi level. That is what these pictures are meant to get you to understand.

Can you provide Any text reference

Ashcroft & Mermin. Or Kittel. Or Steven Simon.
